# Is it possible to send a drag command to an inactive window in the background, using pywin32?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

I am trying to set up a bot for a game that would be able to run in the background (so that I can do other stuff while it runs). I already managed to send click messages to the game window, without activating it. However, I can't seem to make a drag command work.

I noticed that there were at least four ways to send messages to the window, and have tried all the different functions to no avail. The functions I tried were `win32api.SendMessage`, `win32gui.SendMessage` and `PostMessage`. I would love to know the difference between these functions by the way !

Nevertheless, the issue seems to be in the mouse move message, because the click is correctly interpreted by the game, and the code down below (snippet), is basically interpreted as a long click.

I took some inspiration from the following project :
https://www.programcreek.com/python/?project_name=AcademicDog%2Fonmyoji_bot#
, mainly, their `mouse_drag_bg` function in `gameLib.game_ctl`.

**My code**

```
# Separate the mouse move in several smaller moves
move_x = np.linspace(x_start_pix, x_end_pix, num=5, endpoint=True)[0:]
move_y = np.linspace(y_start_pix, y_end_pix, num=5, endpoint=True)[0:]

# Convert the pixel positions so that they can be used by the PostMessage function.
lparam = win32api.MAKELONG(x_start_pix, y_start_pix)
lparam2 = win32api.MAKELONG(x_end_pix, y_end_pix)

# Sometimes mouse move is needed apparently so that the click is registered correctly
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lparam)

# Click
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, lparam)

# Hold and move
for i in range(5):
    x = int(round(move_x[i]))
    y = int(round(move_y[i]))
    win32gui.PostMessage(
       self.hwnd, win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, win32api.MAKELONG(x, y))
    sleep(0.4)
sleep(0.5)

# Release
win32gui.PostMessage(self.hwnd, win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lparam2)
```

I tried separating the mouse move in increments, like they did in the project, because directly indicating a drag from the starting point to the end point didn't work. Unfortunately the code above doesn't work. I tried putting `win32con.MK_LBUTTON` as a `wparam`, in the mouse move message, because, as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove
, it should indicate that the left button of the mouse is held down.

I was under the impression that clicks would work because they are "discrete" commands, and a drag command could be seen as "continuous". But the whole time (slept), the game sees the click.

Any advice is welcome, and thank you for your time :) !