# Different behaviours encountered when posting a mouse scroll message to different windows with win32gui

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, win32gui

I was trying to send scroll commands to a window in the background, when I encountered strange behaviours that I don't really understand.

**The Script**

I wrote a script to illustrate what I encountered. To have it work, I used a Windows 10 system, and had *one* mail window and *one* command prompt window open in the background (not minimised). The script sends a scroll command to both windows with the mouse pointer located at the middle of the window.

In both windows, the cursor should hover over a region that allows for scrolling. The difference lies in the fact that for the mail window, only a portion of the window allows for scrolling (I used these windows because it is most likely that everyone using Windows has these applications).

```
import win32gui as wgui
import win32api as wapi
import win32con as wcon

# This script is meant to try sending scroll messages to a window.


def callback(hwnd, win_list):
    """ Callback for win32gui.EnumWindows : appends the hwnd to win_list."""
    win_list.append(hwnd)


def find_specific_window(tag):
    """  This function finds a specific window and returns its handle and name.
    :param tag: A key word that describes the window we look for.

    .. note:
    Always stops at the first match.
    """
    win_list = []
    wgui.EnumWindows(callback, win_list)

    # Find the first window with the tag in its name:
    hwnd = None
    name = None
    for h in win_list:
        n = wgui.GetWindowText(h)
        if tag in n:
            name = n
            hwnd = h
            break
    return hwnd, name


def scroll_bg(hwnd, pointer_x, pointer_y, child=True, delta=1):
    """ Performs a scroll on a background window with handle hwnd (might need to use FindWindowEx).
    :param pointor_x: relative horizontal position of the mouse (y is vertical).
    :param child: Boolean telling whether to operate on the top child window or the main window.
    """
    # Take the top child window handle
    if child:
        hwnd = wgui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, None, None, None)

    # Transform the mouse coordinates into pixels for the given window.

    # Obtain the window dimensions
    rect = wgui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)

    w = rect[2]  # Width
    h = rect[3]  # Height

    x_pix = int(round(w * pointer_x))
    y_pix = int(round(h * pointer_y))

    print("In scroll_bg: the coordinates for the window {} are : ({}, {})".format(hwnd, x_pix, y_pix))

    # Transform them for the function
    lparam = wapi.MAKELONG(x_pix, y_pix)

    # Transform into wparam
    wparam = wapi.MAKELONG(0, - delta * wcon.WHEEL_DELTA) 
    
    # Hover to the pointer position.
    wgui.PostMessage(hwnd, wcon.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lparam)

    # Scroll
    wgui.PostMessage(hwnd, wcon.WM_MOUSEWHEEL, wparam, lparam)
    wgui.PostMessage(hwnd, wcon.WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lparam)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    window1_tag = "Mail"
    window2_tag = "Command"

    hwnd1 = find_specific_window(window1_tag)
    hwnd2 = find_specific_window(window2_tag)

    print("first window handle: {}, second window handle: {}".format(hwnd1, hwnd2))

    # In both windows we set the pointer at the middle.
    scroll_bg(hwnd1[0], 1/2, 1/2)
    scroll_bg(hwnd2[0], 1/2, 1/2, False)
```

In the script, I defined a `scroll_bg` function that can send the scroll instruction to a given window, identified by `hwnd`, or its first child (by setting `child=True`).

**My Script Result**

Running this script I can observe that the scroll has correctly been sent to the Command Prompt window, but nothing changed for the Mail window, despite targetting scrollable areas in both windows. I must note that I also tried sending the scroll message to the parent window, by running `scroll_bg(hwnd1[0], 1/2, 1/2, False)`, but it didn't work either.

**More Details**

I must also note that I observed this issue in the same context as this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69761948/is-it-possible-to-send-a-drag-command-to-an-inactive-window-in-the-background-u) I wanted to send scroll commands instead of dragging, and managed to successfully scroll in certain areas while not in others (for the same game).

I further observed that giving a scroll command would do the same animation as a click. The weird part about it is that changing the position of `pointer_x` didn't change the position of the animation, and it occurred at the left border of the window (horizontal pixel = 0). It looks like the `pointer_x` is set to 0, and this would explain the script results.

An other point worth mentioning is that maybe the scroll commands can only be interpreted by some other child window and that the `wgui.PostMessage` function sends the scroll commands to the wrong window thus they are not interpreted correctly. I'm a bit confused as to which window I should send the commands to. For instance, in the case of the game, posting messages to the parent window would not work and I had to send them to the first child. So, perhaps, the results of the script could be explained by the fact that I'm not sending to the correct child.

*Versions* I am using:

- `pywin32` v: 300
- `python`  v: 3.7.1

Thank you for your time, and any advice is welcome ! :)

Comment: Posting input messages is not the same as actual input. For example, `SetCapture` works only when the mouse button is down or over the capturing window. Posting a "mouse move" message and a "mouse down" message is not the same as actually moving the mouse and pressing the button.

Comment: I posted "mouse move" messages because I read in this [project](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?project_name=kujan%2FNGU-scripts#), in `inputs.py` , that "mouse move" events could be required for a game to process a posted click message correctly. Nevertheless, would that mean some windows would work differently if their program uses this `SetCapture` function or not, for instance? My goal is not to simulate the "mouse move" etc, but to have a window believe it happened, if that makes sense.

Comment: You can trick a program into thinking that a mouse move happened by posting a message, but if the program then calls the OS to do something about the mouse, the OS is not fooled and will say "The mouse isn't there, silly."

Comment: So, whether I can send a scroll message in the background really depends on the program, and its handling of the message can vary? For instance, the command prompt window accepts the message (most likely because you can scroll anywhere), the Mail window deletes the message, and the game finds the closest point in the window to the mouse position returned by a call to OS. Or perhaps they all take the closest possible point. I reckon there's no way around this ?

Comment: If you want something that is more consistent across programs, use UI automation.

Comment: Thank you !  I think I'll use `pywinauto` for any drag uses, and settle for foreground manipulation in such cases (luckily, they are rare). I was hoping to have everything work in the background so that I could work on the same machine in the mean time. By the way, do you know why programs would check with the OS for the mouse position ? I mean why wouldn't they accept any message given ?

Comment: All you have to do is search for `GetCursorPos` on StackOverflow to find people who are asking the OS for the mouse position. You could ask those people why they're doing that instead of using the coordinates in the message.